# Gmail Java API messages.import + idempotence

Tags: java, scala, gmail, gmail-api

I am using the Java Gmail client in a small Scala application to import messages into a user's mailbox and wanted to understand if the underlying API was idempotent or not.  Specifically I am using this call:

`gmail.users().messages().gmailImport("me", message).execute()`

Before handing this method a `message`, I explicitly set the message ID (`message.setId(<id>`) and am using a GUID for the value (ex: `85e2adbb-d548-4d0b-bc5c-5eabeccd5551`) but this seems to have no effect at all.  In the API response, I always see an upstream ID that looks like `14c777cc5fbac1ec`. Further, even if use this ID in a subsequent call to `gmailImport`, it looks like a new message is imported and I end up with duplicates in my test inbox.

My questions are:

- Is this message ID field strictly something generated by Google and NOT meant for API consumer to send to achieve idempotence? (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages)
- If the answer to ^ is yes, is there any support for idempotence at the API level at all? Or do I essentially have to track sent messages and IDs if I wish to avoid duplicates?

Thanks!